# How do I use Firebase and react to create static information that all my users have access to?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm creating an app with React. I have user accounts, but I don't know how to create static information that everyone will have access to, as well as the option to save it to their account. Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest a course? Please and thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by static information? and have you tried anything?

Comment: You can use Firebase's Firestore or Realtime Database. These are both cloud-hosted databases, so you are able to share data between users depending on the document structure you decide to create.

Comment: @RedBaron I'm creating an application to help people study. At the moment, users must log in and input the information they would like to study for themselves. I want them to be able to do this, but I would also like to have it so that each user can view another index of information that might be useful to them and add it to their account to study if they so wish. I haven't tried anything yet, I wasn't sure what the best way was to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Though most of the examples in Firebase documentation structure data by user, you don't necessarily need to structure it this way.

Check out [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#add_data):

```js
db.collection("users").add({
    first: "Ada",
    last: "Lovelace",
    born: 1815
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

You could use this example & instead of `users` collection just create collection called for instance, `pages_meta`.

In this case (unless you want to build a small CMS) you will not want to populate this collection dynamically like in this example, so, you'll probably populate this collection manually via Firebase UI.

Then you could [read this collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#read_data), and find info of the needed page, for instance, filtering by current page's href.